# Tell Kotlin that a generic type is an interface

Tags: kotlin, generics, delegates, subtyping

Let's say I have a class `Foo`

```
class Foo {
    val noProblem = "Hakuna Matata"
}
```

I now want to decorate it with an ID. Kotlin's delegates make this relatively painless:

```
class IdentifiableFoo(
    val id: Int,
    foo: Foo,
): Foo by foo

interface Foo {
    val noProblem: String
}
class FooImpl: Foo {
    override val noProblem = "Hakuna Matata"
}
```

but let's say I have another class `Bar` that I also want to decorate, and then another `Baz`, and then another ...

I could just create a `IdentifiableXYZ` for each of them, of course.

But what I really want is something akin to

```
class Identifiable<T> (
    val id: Int,
    thing: T
): T by thing
```

That I could just use for all of them.

And yes, there's a very good chance that the language doesn't support something like that, but the error message made me think:

> Only classes and interfaces may serve as supertypes

so can I do some `where` magic or something to tell Kotlin that `T` is required to be an interface?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want an `Identifiable` interface that has the `id` property, so your class implements `Foo` *and* `Identifiable`? Interfaces are better suited for composition like this, and it would be a lot easier than wrangling generics

Comment: If Java and Kotlin had self types, this might be possible, but unfortunately they don't.

Comment: @cactustictacs nope, I specifically want to differentiate betwee a `Foo` that doesn't have an `id` yet and an `Identifiable<Foo>: Foo` that has received an id, without having to write a ton of boilerplate code and without having to weaken `val id: Int` to a nullable type.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in Kotlin. Kotlin only allows super type to be either a class or an interface. `Type parameter` cannot be a super type of some class or interface.

One workaround might be using a base interface for all the interfaces you are using. But not sure it solves your problem.

```
class IdentifiableFoo<T : BaseFoo>(
    val id: Int,
    val foo: T,
) : BaseFoo by foo {

    fun doSomething(a: T.() -> String) {
        println(a.invoke(foo))
    }
}


interface Foo0 : BaseFoo {
    val noProblem: String
}

interface Foo1 : BaseFoo {
    val someProblem: String
}

class FooImpl : Foo0 {
    override val noProblem = "Hakuna Matata"
}

class Foo1Impl() : Foo1 {
    override val someProblem: String = "Some Problem"
}

interface BaseFoo {}
```

Usage:

```
IdentifiableFoo<Foo0>(2, FooImpl()).doSomething {
    this.noProblem
} // Prints "Hakuna Matata"

IdentifiableFoo<Foo1>(2, Foo1Impl()).doSomething {
    this.someProblem
} // Prints "Some Problem"
```

[Playground link](https://pl.kotl.in/dNT0CvzUG)

Comment: Afraid that doesn't solve the problem. I just mentioned it in a comment but what I want to do is differentiate betwee a `Foo` that doesn't have an `id` yet and an `Identifiable<Foo>: Foo` that has received an id, without having to write a ton of boilerplate code and without having to weaken `val id: Int` to a nullable type. In your attempt, `Identifiable<Foo1>` requires manual extra indirection to access `someProblem` and the `Foo0` and `Foo1` interfaces don't actually serve any purpose.